# pdftk input pdf as string example, possible?

Tags: php, pdftk

im using the php-pdtfk-toolkit found @t [github.com/bensquire/php-pdtfk-toolkit](http://github.com/bensquire/php-pdtfk-toolkit), 
to merge multiple pdfs, the basic example is

```
$pdftk=new pdftk();
$pdftk->setInputFile(array("filename" => 'example.pdf', 'start_page' => 2));
$pdftk->setInputFile(array("filename" => 'example2.pdf', 'rotation' => 100));
$pdftk->_renderPdf();
```

if i had a pdf as a string, there is a way to use pdftk without creating temporary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. The package is just a wrapper around the pdftk binary. pdftk expects filenames and so does the PHP package

Comment: ey!,, currently iam researching if a "virtual" file can be created with a string... ANYWAY, THANKS n__n

Comment: would be hard. especially hard as its just a wrapper around an `exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftk ....')` call. Why not save to a temporary file? using `tmpfile()` for example?

Comment: hey!, it seems tmpfile() can help here!!... you are THE MAN, thanks again!! :3